# Riemannian metric in Layer Normalization

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, normalization

I'm reading a paper about Layer normalization, and I couldn't find any clear explanation for this part:

[image]

Q1. Can anyone describe the derivation of the first equation in (8)?

Q2. I cannot understand the second paragraph. What does "The curvature of a Riemannian manifold is entirely captured by its Riemannian metric, whose quadratic form is denoted as ds^2." mean?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.